# How can I prevent attachments being encoded when being sent via Indy

Tags: delphi, indy

I have successfully written a program which sends Hebrew HTML emails coded as UTF-8 along with embedded pictures and attachments.

I have noticed that whilst emails with attachments of type JPG or TXT get sent rapidly, emails with PDF attachments take a long time (a minute) to be sent. I arranged for a tmemo component to receive the AStatusText string from the SMTP component's OnStatus event, and saw that the program was encoding both the text (correct) and the attachment (incorrect).

How can I prevent the attachment from being encoded and thus have the email sent faster?

Here is the log from the SMTP component showing the time

```
18:44:01 smtp: Connected.
18:44:04 smtp: Encoding text
18:44:04 smtp: Encoding attachment
18:44:04 smtp: Encoding attachment
18:45:05 smtp: Disconnecting.
18:45:05 smtp: Disconnected.
18:45:05 disconnected
```

The minute was necessary to encode a PDF file of size 491KB. During this time the program is unresponsive (I thought that the program was hung until I looked at the log).

Maybe I should ask a slightly different question: *why* does this have to be encoded?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. *Everything* gets encoded. That's how information gets transmitted digitally — by choosing an encoding for representing that information in a way that can be sent and received. If you don't like *how* it's been encoded, that's another matter. What did you see, and what did you expect to see instead?

Comment: The key is that emails are a text only medium, and you cannot just start putting binary in the content. So protocols were created to allow you to have not only a message, but a "multi-part" message that includes encoded content. The encoding restricts the range of characters to those allowed. It makes it bigger, but it is as good as it can go. Basically, large files are best sent not by email. Taking a minute is normal.

Comment: A minute for a 800kb email?  Not where I live.  I can attach and send 6 megabyte files in less than 30 seconds.  Your mileage may vary.

Comment: IMHO it's better if you use a profiler to see in detail where that large amount of time is consumed. You're pointing at the encoding process, but I bet it is somewhere else. It can be the I/O on your machine (defective disk, local anti virus scanning, slow local network if UNC path, etc), or waiting the server response (slow network, heavy load server, etc), or maybe something else.

You can also check how much time takes to encode it by asking INDY to encode the same data in a isolated way.

Comment: install wireshark on your computer and do a network trace. (use smtp as filter in wireshark). Chances are big that the delay is on the server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All attachments are ALWAYS encoded using MIME64, or else your email will not be readable by anybody but you.  It isn't your job to change how internet email works.

The reason for your delay is probably either that the PDF is being "virus scanned" by your hosting company, or on the other hand, if you are attaching a giant PDF, and it's taking a minute to encode it, I'm not surprised that a giant PDF file, when converted to MIME64, which is not a step you can skip, takes a long time.    But your PDF is 491 KB, which is miniscule, so the delay may be on the server side, which may be scanning your PDF through. Remember that the SMTP process is a dialog of your-side-sends, then the other-side-responds. A delay before the other side responds is not something you can fix without understanding why the delay happens. The "no encoding" idea you had is not reasonable.

However, virus/spam-scan is a reasonable hypothesis, which may be adding 30 seconds to your already-30-second normal transmit time. To test that hypothesis, rename your pdf from "test.pdf" to "test.p@d@f$", and see if the transmit time drops from 60 seconds to about 30 seconds. You haven't stated how fast your internet pipe is, or how large you think the MIME64 encoded EMAIL may be, but it could be 1.5x larger than your PDF, so around 600 to 800 kbytes. If you are on a very slow DSL or ISDN connection, then that would explain it too.

Comment: Changing the file name didn't make any difference to the time, but it's an interesting idea.

Comment: In that case, profiling your code with a real profiler, like AQTime, and using tools like wireshark as other commenters suggested, will help you see if the delay is on the Client or Server.  You've definitely been premature in guessing where your delay is. Assumptions are sometimes the enemy of the developer.